# How to remove an icon in a QTreeWidgetItem?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qtreewidgetitem

I have a `QTreeWidget` with `QTreeWidgetItems` and sometimes the items have an icon. So I set the icon using:

```
self.setIcon(0, icon)
```

But how do I remove that icon again?

```
self.setIcon(0, None)
```

gives

```
TypeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem.setIcon' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide.QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem.setIcon(int, NoneType)
Supported signatures:
  PySide.QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem.setIcon(int, PySide.QtGui.QIcon)
```

Comment: What if you set an empty icon? For example: `foo.setIcon(0, QIcon());` (c++).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For completeness I write down the comment of [vahancho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27838473/qtreewidgetitem-how-to-remove-an-icon#comment44080979_27838473) as an answer.

Set an empty icon:

```
item.setIcon(column, QtGui.QIcon())
```

This also makes sense since even without setting an icon

```
item.icon(column)
```

does return a `QIcon` object. So Qt probably internally presets the icons with empty icons anyway.